# MySQL sign in error "ERROR 1524 (HY000): Plugin '*6BB4837EB74329105EE4568DDA7DC67ED2CA2AD9' is not loaded"

Tags: mysql

When I use MySQL and sign in, I always get the following error:

```
[guhan@localhost ~]$ mysql -u root -p 
Enter password: 
ERROR 1524 (HY000): Plugin '*6BB4837EB74329105EE4568DDA7DC67ED2CA2AD9' is not loaded
[guhan@localhost ~]$
```

Answer (score 1):

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-user.html
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/account-names.html

```
/etc/init.d/mysqldstart --skip-grant-table

mysql -uroot

use mysql

select user,password,plugin from user;
```

Look at the user table and inside the plugin check if it is `mysql_native_plugin`, if not, change it.